# tabular & multirow: taking a multirow back to a single

Tags: tables, multirow, tabu

I have a table that I needed `multirow` for say column 2, but for column 3, I am putting the best result from column 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & 4 & 4\\
                   & 5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here A is vertically centered for the `multirow`. I would like 4 to be able to achieve this same look.

If I do `& 4 & 4\\`, it will be aligned at the top, and vice verse for `5`.

What can I do to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I am missing something but why don't you use another multi row for 4 like

```
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & 4 & \multirow{2}{*}{4}\\
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & 4 & \multirow{2}{*}{4}\\
                   & 5
\end{tabular}

Another one

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multirow{4}{*}{A} & 4 & \multirow{4}{*}{4} \\
                   & 5 &                    \\
                   & 3 &                    \\
                   & 1 &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know that would work.

Comment: @dustin It happens to all of us some times :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use stacks, perhaps, instead of `multirow`.  Here I give two examples.  Note: the `\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}` in the preamble is necessary, because `\baselineskip` (the default long-stack skip) is zeroed in the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & \Centerstack{4\\5} & 4
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & \Centerstack{1\\2\\3\\4\\5} & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer but I was hoping for something with multirow since I already built my table (very lengthy and pain to change).  If no one can provide a solution with the current set up, I will inevitably change it to your form.

Comment: @dustin Understood completely.